# Branch cut in complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, how can I integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{du}{\pi}\frac{1}{z-x+\left(z+x\right)u^{2}}.$$

I believe the answer is $\text{sgn}\left(\text{Re} z\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^{2}-x^{2}}}$. I am having trouble obtaining the sign function, which I think comes from branch cuts involving square root and log.

Comment: When you wrote $z\in\mathbb C$, I suppose that you meant $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb R$.

Comment: The specfic case I am interested in indeed has nonreal $z$. Is the question not well-defined for real $z$?

Comment: Thank about what the integral becomes is $z=0$ and $x=1$. Or, even worse, if $z=x=0$.

Comment: Thank you. I have amended the question.